# Ruby で書いたこの FizzBuzz コードを Python で書くとどうなるのでしょうか?

Tags: ruby, python

普段はRubyを使っています。Pythonの勉強を始めたのですが、早速躓いていたので教えて下さい。

```
class FizzBuzz
  def self.fizz?(i)
    i > 0 && (i % 3) == 0
  end

  def self.buzz?(i)
    i > 0 && (i % 5) == 0
  end

  def self.fizz_buzz?(i)
    fizz?(i) && buzz?(i)
  end

  def self.to_p(i)
    case
    when fizz?(i) && !fizz_buzz?(i)
      'Fizz'
    when buzz?(i) && !fizz_buzz?(i)
      'Buzz'
    when fizz_buzz?(i)
      'FizzBuzz'
    else
      i
    end
  end
end

1.upto(100) do |i|
  puts FizzBuzz.to_p(i)
end
```

これをPythonで書こうとしてるのですが、書き方がわかりません。
以下が私の書いたPythonのコードです。(実行できません)
「Pythonらしく書くにはこうするとよい」などのアドバイスもいただけると幸いです。

```
class FizzBuzz:
    @classmethod
    def is_fizz(i):
        return (i > 0 and (i % 3) == 0)

    @classmethod
    def is_buzz(i):
        return (i > 0 and (i % 5) == 0)

    @classmethod
    def is_fizz_buzz(i):
        return (self.is_fizz(i) and self.is_buzz(i))

    @classmethod
    def to_print(i):
        if self.is_fizz(i) and not self.is_fizz_buzz(i):
            return 'Fizz'
        elif self.is_buzz(i) and not self.fizz_buzz(i):
            return 'Buzz'
        elif self.fizz_buzz(i):
            return 'FizzBuzz'
        else:
            return i

for i in range(1, 101):
    print FizzBuzz.to_print(i)
```

Comment: ConstructorがないとPythonでは無駄なclassですね

Answer (score 5):

クラス勉強には、上記のものはいいと思いますが、関数を使えばもっと簡単になります。
（ちなみにpythonでは、.to_print()のようなメソッドは、あまり見ないので、ここでは、rubyぽっくpythonを書いている感じがします）

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
        return 'FizzBuzz'
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        return 'Fizz'
    elif n % 5 == 0:
        return 'Buzz'
    else:
        return str(n)

for i in range(1, 101):
    print(fizzbuzz(i))
```

Comment: +1 RubyっぽいPythonでした

Answer (score 4):

最低限動くように修正するなら、こんな感じです。

```
class FizzBuzz:

    @staticmethod
    def is_fizz(i):
        return i > 0 and (i % 3) == 0

    @staticmethod
    def is_buzz(i):
        return i > 0 and (i % 5) == 0

    @classmethod
    def is_fizz_buzz(cls, i):
        return cls.is_fizz(i) and cls.is_buzz(i)

    @classmethod
    def to_print(cls, i):
        if cls.is_fizz(i) and not cls.is_fizz_buzz(i):
            return 'Fizz'
        elif cls.is_buzz(i) and not cls.is_fizz_buzz(i):
            return 'Buzz'
        elif cls.is_fizz_buzz(i):
            return 'FizzBuzz'
        else:
            return i

for i in range(1, 101):
    print FizzBuzz.to_print(i)
```

Comment: なるほど。同じクラス内のメソッドを呼び出すには`cls`を引数に渡して使うんですね。